# preg_match returns Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, curl, preg-match, web-crawler

I'm making Torrent PHP Crawler and I have problem, here's my code:

```
// ... the cURL codes (they're working) ...
// Contents of the Page
$contents = curl_exec($crawler->curl);

// Find the Title
$pattern = "/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/s";
preg_match($pattern, $contents, $titlematches);
echo "Title - ".$titlematches[1]."<br/>";

// Find the Category
$pattern = "/Тип<\/td><td(?>[^>]+)>((?>[^<]+))<\/td>/s";
preg_match($pattern, $contents, $categorymatches);
echo "Category - ".$categorymatches[1]."<br/>";
```

The HTML page ("Тип" means Category and "Филми" means Movies):

```
<title>The Matrix</title>
<!--Some Codes Here--!>
<tr><td>Тип</td><td valign="top" align=left>Филми</td></tr>
<!--Some Codes Here--!>
```

The Result:

```
Title - The Matrix
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/spider.php on line 117
```

It's showing the title but not the category.. why is that?
I've tried to echo `$categorymatches[0]`, `$categorymatches[2]`, `$categorymatches[3]` without any luck.

Comment: This means that `contents` does not create a match for `categorymatches`.  Also, comments are closed with `-->`, not `--!>`

Comment: `$contents` doesn't hold the correct HTML data. Try to echo it soon after the `curl_exec()`, and see what appears. I tried it locally with the HTML you provided and it worked fine, it matched perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assuming that preg_match actually finds a match. It's better to test if it did so.

```
$pattern = "/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/s"; 
$matchCount = preg_match($pattern, $contents, $titlematches); 
if ($matchCount > 0) {
    echo $titlematches[1]."<br/>";
} else {
    // do something else, 'cos no match found
}
```

Note that you might want to use a switch or two with preg_match: this will only find a result if "title" is used, not "TITLE" or "Title", so using the case-insensitive /i switch might be an idea; or the  tag might be on a different line to the value, and to the , so the multiline switch /m could be useful.

And the same principle applies to all your preg_match checks

**EDIT**

It looks as though your category match is testing for a utf-8 string, so try using the /u switch

Comment: Yep, the problem was in the charset - I just convert the crawler.php to ANSI and it's working now (the page that it's crawling is with Windows-1251 encoding) :) Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be `if ($matchCount > 0)` -> match found?